# pyspark value of column when other column has first nonmissing value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following pyspark dataframe `df`:

```
id     date   var1   var2
1         1   NULL      2
1         2      b      3
2         1      a   NULL
2         2      a      1
```

I want the first non missing observation for all `var*` columns and additionally the value of date where this is from, i.e. the final result should look like:

```
id     var1   dt_var1  var2    dt_var2
1         b         2     2          1  
2         a         1     1          2
```

Getting the values is straightforward using

```
df.orderBy(['id','date']).groupby('id').agg(
  *[F.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in ['var1', 'var2']]
)
```

But I fail to see how I could get the respective dates. I could loop variable for variable, drop missing, and keep the first row. But this sounds like a poor solution that will not scale well, as it would require a separate dataframe for each variable.

I would prefer a solution that scales to many columns (`var3`, `var4`,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use groupby if you want to get the first non-null according to date ordering. The order is not guaranteed after a groupby operation even if you called orderby just before.

You need to use window functions instead. To get the date associated with each `var` value you can use this trick with structs:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w = (Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
     )

df1 = df.select(
    "id",
    *[F.first(
        F.when(F.col(x).isNotNull(), F.struct(x, F.col("date").alias(f"dt_{x}"))),
        ignorenulls=True).over(w).alias(x)
      for x in ["var1", "var2"]
      ]
).distinct().select("id", "var1.*", "var2.*")

df1.show()
#+---+----+-------+----+-------+
#| id|var1|dt_var1|var2|dt_var2|
#+---+----+-------+----+-------+
#|  1|   b|      2|   2|      1|
#|  2|   a|      1|   1|      2|
#+---+----+-------+----+-------+
```